# DateAdd/DateDiff functions in H2 and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, date, h2, datediff, dateadd

I am writing an munit test case and mocking my real SQL Server database tables with H2 in-memory instance.

My query has date condition to return records from previous month, so I was looking for something that works with SQL Server as well as H2. Finally I found below which syntactically works in both.

```
select 
    DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', GETDATE()) - 1, '1900-01-01');
```

In SQL Server, it properly gives me start date of previous month but in H2, it is giving me start date of current month. If change `-1` to `2` then H2 works but SQL Server returns the wrong date.

Can someone please help with how I can get correct syntax?

Same problem with last day of previous month -

```
select 
    DATEADD(D, -1, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, '1900-01-01', GETDATE()), '1900-01-01'))
```

Comment: Why not to just use SQL Server and avoid all issues like this?

Comment: Usually, all external dependencies are mocked in test case to ensure they are always executable in any environment. Also, these are integrated with builds so dont want to hit SQL server on every build.

Comment: SQL Express is free, you can use that for testing.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I cannot change that db choice. Any help with H2 please?